# Why fwrite doesn't work in writing binary mode?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{

    FILE* bfp = fopen("student.dat", "wb"); 
    int n = 1452;       
    fseek(bfp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, bfp);

    FILE* rfp = fopen("student.dat", "rb");
    int read = 0;
    fread(&read, sizeof(read), 1, rfp);
    printf("%d", read);

    fclose(bfp);
    fclose(rfp);
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get 0 when I print it out?
I tried "w" mode, but it didn't work. How can I enter it?

Comment: You should `fclose(bfp)` to ensure the data is flushed to file before opening it for the read. Also should check the return value of all the function calls for any errors

Comment: I moved the  'fclose(bfp)'  position right after the 'fwrite'. But how can I find this value of all the function calls for any errors?

Comment: `if (fopen(..) == NULL) { perror("file open failed"); return -1; }`. That is, check the return value of each function call. Read the man page for each function and it will tell you what value is returned on error.

Comment: I tried to code it, but it's not "NULL". "file open error" didn't come out. But if I typed "wb" in 1452, the output should be 1452.? Why does the number 371722 come out?

Comment: I ran your code with `fclose(bfp)` moved up to immediately after the `fwrite`. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Oh my God!!!!!!!!!! I solved it. Thank you very much. You'll be blessed.